# calling ExecuteReader() from catch block

Tags: sqlexception

I have the following code and when exception happens the ExecuteReader() in Catch block will hang the app.

My question is why the hang? I can't perform query inside of Catch block if query exception happens in general?

```
Try {
   // some SQL queries
}
catch (SqlException odbcEx) {
   // do some queries with IDbCommand::ExecuteReader()
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   // Handle generic ones here.
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecuteReader()` keeps hold of your SQL connection. What you want to do is wrap a using statement round it. Also, you can't perform a SQL query because you have essentially `errored` and lost scope of your SQL connection variable. If you want, you can do some further SQL in the exception block by instantiating a new instance of your `reader` and `connection`, however ideally close of your existing connection before doing so. If you use a `datatable` you won't keep hold of the SQL connection. Perhaps something to look at.

For example:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
try {
   // some SQL queries
}
catch (SqlException odbcEx) {
   // do some queries with IDbCommand::ExecuteReader()
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   // Handle generic ones here.
}
finally {
  conn.Close();
}
}
```

This way you are disposing of your connection and not keeping hold of it.

Comment: so what's happening here is that ExecuteReader() tries to do a query based upon a corrupted connection?

Comment: Not sure corrupted is the correct term. Perhaps in an unusable state / crashed. When it does this it leaves the SQL connection open and using a DataReader you can have a single connection open at any given time thus you can't use the same DataReader unless you close the reader and the connection its associated with. You might want to lookup SqlDataAdapter and DataTable.